# Java BufferedReader check if readLine() will block

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader, blocking, inputstreamreader

I need to create an activity, that would display Android logs in real-time:

```
//In background thread:
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
String line = "";
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null && !isInterrupted())
{
    log.append(line);
    mLoggerActivity.updateLog(log.toString()); 
}

...

public class LoggerActivity extends Activity
{
    private void updateLog(final String log) // Will be called from inner class
    {
        mUIThreadHadler.post
        (
            new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    mLoggerView.setText(log);
                }
            }
        );
    }
...
}
```

I think, that updating UI every line is not efficient - but what another options I have? I need something as bufferedReader.canReadLine() - so I can batch update StringBuilder before posting log.toString() to main thread.

Comment: I think you should avoid that approach. Calling toString() on StringBuffer is creating new String object every time. And all advantages of StringBuffer are disappearing. And updating your UI after each line also not good. Even if you make that happen after every 10th line. I advice you to show message like "log is loading", read it to end and display. One time.

Comment: I need to create an activity, that would display app log in real-time. 10 lines is only for example - I want to find that number experimentally.

Comment: @progmob Are you looking for [`available`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available) method?

Comment: Yes, but it will be not cool if I have to read logs not per-line, but per-byte...